# Problema con función getchar en C

Tags: c, get

Llevo un rato largo con esta tontería, ¿alguien podría decirme qué es lo que está mal? Al ejecutarlo no me pide ingresar ningún carácter y por ende no imprime nada :

```
char h = getchar();
printf("%c", h);
```

Comment: Antes de la instruccion getchar que tienes??

Comment: La causa más probable es que antes hayas leído un entero o flotante con `scanf()`. En ese caso `scanf()` habrá ido leyendo caracteres hasta llegar a uno que no sea dígito y habrá parado allí. Por ejemplo en el típico retorno de carro que se mete tras escribir el número. Ese carácter está aún en el buffer de teclado esperando ser leido y será lo primero que encuentre `getchar()`, sin necesidad de esperar. Y lo que luego imprime es justo ese retorno de carro que ha leído.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo utilizar `scanf()`

Uso:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;

    printf("Elige un numero: ");
    scanf("%i", &i);
    for (int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
            printf("%i \n", j);
    }
}
```

Resultado:

```
Elige un numero: 5

1
2
3
4
5
```

Este es un simple programa para contar la cantidad de veces que se indique, utilizando scanf.